# CORS issue in AngularJS on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cors

My app is written in AngularJS on Rails. I tried to fix the CORS issue with either Angular way or Rails way. It still doesnt work for "POST" method, and "GET" method it's alright.

I already put this code in my app.

```
myapp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
   delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With']; 
}])
```

and Rails Application Controller
I also put this up.

```
after_filter  :set_access_control_headers

def set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
end
```

I also tried the gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: There is more to CORS than just that one header

Answer (score 0):

To learn more about CORS I really recommend this [article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

Then, since you are using Rails you can follow the [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) instructions:

in `config/application.rb`

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

Also be sure to check this sample Rails 4 configuration: https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/blob/master/examples/rails4/config/application.rb